# Excel 2011 - make a cell display another cells value if its adjacent cell is equal to a 4th cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2011

For example, if the value in I31 equals a value in column A (lets say A5) I want to display B5 (so same row) in a new cell (say I32). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the described 4 cell example you could use:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(I31,A1:A56,0)),"Value Not Found",INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",MATCH(I31,A1:A56,0)),TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it! I actually was able to use =LOOKUP(). Worked the first time!